# How do I print 4 impressions of a one page document onto a single page in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I need to print a full size one page document in Word, reduced to 1/4 scale, in four separate panes on the sheet.  How do I do that?  Is there a way to preview?

If you are going to tell me to use Printer Options, 4 pages per sheet, how do I get it to print all four, and not just the one in the upper left-hand corner?

Comment: Curiosity forces me to ask: What happened when you tried Printer Options, 4 pages per sheet?

Comment: It only printed the one in the upper left-hand corner.

Comment: Be sure that "Print Range" was set to "All" and that really should be all that needs to happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use printer options as earlier suggested, but select "pages" instead of "all", and enter 1,1,1,1 in adjacent entry window - worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Can you just duplicate the first page 3 more times so you have a 4-page document and then print 4-up?

Seems a little low-rent, but it would work!

Comment: I dont think that will help as the four pages will contain duplicate data - what RH needs is a splitof the contents by four, not the contents four times methinks

Comment: @Critical Skill: That would be nice, but I don't think that's how it works.  I tried printing 4 copies and I got 4 pages, each with one impression in the upper left hand corner.  @Chris: Anyway, it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 portrait pages in word that are identical.
Print to a PDF.
Then print from the PDF viewer - four pages per sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Mail section > labels` (in french: `publipostage > étiquettes`), and then click the `options` button. You have a life of labels vendors, and you can choose one and then click `print` or `new document`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing so I opened my document and then went up to the toolbar and over to "insert" then to "Break", then under Section break types select "Next page", then OK. Do that 3 times, that way the one Word doc you started with will now be 4 pages.

After you created 4 pages, go to "file" down to "print", then down in the bottom right under zoom. You will see pages per sheet, select 4 pages, then hit OK.

It should now print that first original document 4 times on one Word document.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is in page ranges, make sure to put 1,1,1,1. I spent all morning working on this and it works best in word. My PDF converter would not let me change my page range as it was only one page.

Comment: The Page-range with 1,1,1,1 option works in Portrait but not in Landscape. Both the document and the printer are setup with A4 Landscape mode; yet the printing is only Portrait in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a Mac using preview & want to print for copies of one page on a sheet:

1. Open up the 'thumbnails' tab.
2. Hold the 'alt' button then click and drag the thumbnail down - it will create a copy of it in the same document. Do this four times.
3. On printer options go to 'Layout' then select 'Pages per Sheet > 4'
4. Print away!

Comment: Your answer is about Preview, not about Word. You're not answering the question. Please read [Answer] before answering.